# how to access props.deviceType

Tags: reactjs, carousel

My problem is kind of simple. I'm trying to access `this.props.deviceType`  in order to use it in react-multi-carousel props, the problem is that I get a  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')` and I don't know how to fix that. 
Here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PastEventCard from "./PastEventCard";
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";
function PastEventSection(props) {
  const responsive = {
  return (
      <Carousel
        autoPlay={this.props.deviceType !== "mobile" ? true : false}
        centerMode={this.props.deviceType !== "mobile" ? true : false}
        removeArrowOnDeviceType={["tablet", "mobile"]}
        deviceType={this.props.deviceType}
      >
        <PastEventCard title="" description="" imgURL="" />
        <PastEventCard title="" description="" imgURL="" />
        <PastEventCard title="" description="" imgURL="" />
      </Carousel>
  );
}
export default PastEventSection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is a functional component. you don't access to props using `this` key
you just access to it as any other function argument simply `props.anything`.
that's why you don't have the this key and it's undefined.
In Class based component we access props using `this` key because props is a property of the Component class

Comment: Ah that was simple, thanks for your Help

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import PastEventCard from "./PastEventCard";

import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";

function PastEventSection({ deviceType }) {
  const responsive = { // what is it?
  return (
      <Carousel
        autoPlay={deviceType !== "mobile"}
        centerMode={deviceType !== "mobile"}
        removeArrowOnDeviceType={["tablet", "mobile"]}
        deviceType={deviceType}
      >
        <PastEventCard title="" description="" imgURL="" />
        <PastEventCard title="" description="" imgURL="" />
        <PastEventCard title="" description="" imgURL="" />
      </Carousel>
  );
};

export default PastEventSection;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help man it worked
can you help me with this one please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73866712/how-to-add-linear-gradient-color-and-image-url-at-same-time-in-reactjs-inline-st

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAhmed in functional component no need to contact `this` because functional components have no context. instead, we refer to the first argument, which is the object `props`. and also use destructuring to get the field `deviceType`.